# Using a member variable of a class in the class itself in C++ / Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen

I'm trying to create a class for a geometric object like say a polytope of dimension n. So i have an `unsigned int dim` member variable and other member variables like the center vector of the object (variable type defined by an external library, Eigen). The thing is I need to/should specify the dimensionality of the center vector in the member variable but I'd only know what the dimensionality of the object is once defined by the constructors.

(To those who are familiar with Eigen, I believe it is possible to just dynamically define the dimensionality of matrices and solve this whole problem but I was looking at an alternative)

The constructors are either 1) an empty constructor, 2) constructor with dimensionality, or 3) a constructor with the center vector, from which i can then save the dimensionality.

Of course this doesn't work in C++ for certain reasons since the dimensionality of the center vector is not defined at time of compilation. How do I solve this at elegantly as possible and still be able to statically define my vector?

Comment: Can you provide some very simple example code highlighting the C++-specific problem without going too much into mathematical details?

Comment: A minimal reproducible example....would be helpful. i.e. your code that "does not work" cleaned up so as other people can make sense/reproduce what you are experiencing.